# How to receive messages from Xbox gamepad in uwp?

Tags: uwp, xbox, gamepad-api

I know that I can get the button status through the method under `Windows.Gaming.Input`, but I can't get the USB command sent by the gamepad, because the gamepad has some non-standard functions, such as multiple key mappings, I need to get the current mapping.

`GipGameControllerProvider.SendReceiveMessage` looks like what I want, but calling it will get an error: **the request is not supported (exception from HResult: 0x80070032).**

This is a related question:[How to communicate with Xbox one controller in uwp](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/12731/how-to-communicate-with-xbox-one-controller-in-uwp.html)

Thank you for reading and have a good day!

Comment: About this question, I have replied to you on [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/12731/how-to-communicate-with-xbox-one-controller-in-uwp.html), you can check it.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I've checked it, thanks. And I feel helpless now. That's why I asked many repeated questions :(

Comment: Yes, I understand. If the team responds to me, I will update on Q&A in time.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. I appreciate it